# Насколько адекватно делать вот так

Tags: php, html

```
    function page_footer()
{
    echo '  <footer>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row" id="stayhere">
                        <div class="col">
                            <a href="" class="heading">contact us</a>
                            <a href="" class="heading">Shipping & Returns</a>
                            <a href="" class="heading">Gift Cards</a>
                            <a href="" class="heading">Privacy</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <a href="" class="heading">About US</a>
                            <a href="" class="heading">The Concept</a>
                            <a href="" class="heading">Press</a>
                            <a href="" class="heading">Artists</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col sub">
                            <div class="heading">stay in touch</div>
                            <form action="" class="col">
                                <input type="text" name="email-sub" class="email-sub">
                                <button type="submit" class="heading sub">subscribe</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row" id="footer-menu">
                        <p class="heading">copyright&copy;2017</p>

                        <div>
                            <a href="" class="heading">blog</a>
                            <a href="" class="heading">about us</a>
                            <a href="" class="heading">contact us</a>
                            <a href="" class="heading">faq</a>
                            <a href="" class="heading">my account</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="social row">
                            f
                            t
                            i
                            t
                            p
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>';
}
```

и в html вызывать

```
<? page_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: а какая необходимость возвращать статический html из функции?

Comment: вообще никакой, но не хочется на каждую страничку сайта копипастить html

Comment: @Istinnavvine Так и не попипасьте. Сохраните код футера в некий файл и подключайте на страницах именно его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае имеется статический код html, даже без вставок php. Удобнее данный код футера вынести в отдельный файл и подключать на страничках уже его. Так будет легко вносить изменения в футер в одном месте - в одном файле. Изменения будут сразу применяться на всём сайте.

Иногда подобный код сохраняют не в отдельном файле, а где-нибудь в базе данных, привязанной к проекту в таблице, где лежат все подобные шаблоны шапкок и подвалов сайта.

Как у вас - через функцию - следует писать в том случае, если код не является статическим и его содержимое, например, является результатом работы каких-то функций и динамически футер собирается "на лету".

Comment: а в каком плане в отдельный файл, просто подключать footer.html, инклюдом?

Comment: @Istinnavvine Вполне подойдёт, впрочем, обычно сохраняют в файл с расширением php, чтобы всё-таки можно было потом в этот шаблон делать динамические вставки. И да, подключить можно инклюдом. Хотя его уже можете вставлять в страницы по месту, а можете описать как раз вашу функцию и вызывать именно её.

Comment: понял, спасибки :)*

Answer (score -1):

Описанный метод используется зачастую в шаблонах, по этому да, за частую это адекватный подход

Тока храните информацию html не в функции а в файле, так проще

Answer (score -1):

Вполне адекватный подход. Например, если требуется сгенерировать много подобных элементов, можно вызывать их из функции циклом или по условию. При этом функции можно передавать параметр. Хотя здесь `<footer>`, который в документе должен быть один. Но, например, с `<section>` вполне годный вариант.