# HTML верстка: сбор блоков

Tags: html5, layout

Делаю верстку сайта. Опыта совсем мало, использую HTML CSS JS, без бека и фреймворков Angular, React и т.д.

Сейчас набралось некоторое количество страниц, и у каждой страницы полностью одинаковый Header, SideBar, Footer, скритпы и стили. Не удобно, та и что-то можно пропустить/забыть, когда меняю код во всех страницах, а меняю я полностью одинаковый код. И потом обнаруживать, что в одной из страниц, не так как у всех остальных. Нужно чтобы я мог сделать правку в коде, и чтобы она отобразилась во всех страницах

Есть ли возможность вызова слоев, например есть html файл(назвем его header.html), в нему прописан Header, и в homepage.html вызываем все что прописано в header.html? и тогда у нас получается некоторый фракинштейн, который собирается вот такими слоями

homepage.html который у меня есть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

homepage.html который мне нужен
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы используете сборщик? Если нет, то самое простое - изменить расширение html на php и собирать страницы с помощью include('footer.php')

Answer (score 1):

1. Примеры кода лучше приводить не скриншотами, а текстом. Так их всегда можно изменить и поправить в самом вопросе, куски кода можно копировать, текст участвует в поиске и может быть полезен для базы знаний SO.
2. Если у вас имеется хотя бы простой веб-сервер (на хостинге-то он по-любому будет), то используйте php. Файлы вёрстки перевести из html в php. Шапку, подвал и сайдбар вынесите в отдельные файлы и затем подключайте их в нужных местах ваших страниц, например, через include.

Тут как-то проскакивал вопрос? я там давал ответ, не то чтобы он совсем такой же как у вас, но вы [почитайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1165824/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA/1165837#1165837).